# Cannot link LIBEVENT as C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, libevent

Why this does not work, file `test.c`:

```
#include <event.h>
int main(void)
{
    event_init();
    return 0;
}
```

Then:
`gcc -o test.o -c test.c` runs OK, but

Link:
`g++ -o test -levent test.o` produces

```
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `event_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So it cannot be linked as `C++`. How to solve this? I need to link it as `C++` and compile as `C`.

Comment: `g++ -o test test.o -levent`...

Comment: Yes, order matters a lot

Comment: Try `g++ -o test test.o -levent`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question has been asked many times. On Linux, you **should** put **libraries after object and source** files in the compilation command. So try

```
g++ -Wall -g -c mytest.cc 
g++ -Wall -g mytest.o -levent -o mytest
```

Avoid calling your test program [`test`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_test.htm) which is an existing utility or shell builtin.

As a newbie, remember to always compile with all warnings asked `-Wall` and for debugging `-g` and learn to use `gdb`

Comment: I object that compiler warnings and debuggers are "newbie" tools. Compiler warnings should be mandatory for *everyone*.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that (remember, I am not a native English speaker). I just meant that newbies often forget to enable warnings and debugging. Once you are more skilled in C or C++ programming, you won't forget them!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. "As a newbie, *remember to enable* ..." :-)

Comment: If the question has been asked many times, why did you bother answering it?

Comment: Because it is Friday evening (in Paris), and I have some time... :-) :-)

Comment: Explanation of *why* libraries after objects rule: http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html